# How can I associate an NSManagedObject to the context after it has been initialised?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

For example, if I have an `NSManagedObject` named `Items`, and I want to set the `ManagedObjectContext` later (not when initialised), how would I do that?

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
Items *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Items" 
                                                inManagedObjectContext:_context];
```

That automatically associates it to `_context`.

But what if I want to do this:

```
Items *item = [[Items alloc] init];
item.first = @"bla";
item.second = @"bla bla";
```

And I would want to pass that object to another method which would then associate it with the context and save it.

So is there any way to just do a simple `item.managedObjectContext = _context` or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach would be perfectly valid...

```
Items *item = [[Item alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
item.first = @"blah";
item.second = @"blah blah";
```

You're then free to pass this object around to where its needed and when you're ready to commit it to a managed object context, simply insert it and save.

```
[managedObjectContext insertObject:item];
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Comment: But to get the entity, won't I need to create a NSEntityDescription object, which will need a model, which in turn needs the context for the managed object? I'm trying to centralize the processing for the coredata in a manager class, so if I can just pass a simple Items object then that'd be ideal. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If I add `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:nil];` before the item gets initialised, it fails because it requires the context in order to locate the object model for entity name `Items`

Comment: You're correct. I must have misunderstood your question. I don't understand why you're delaying the creation of an NSManagedObjectContext. To be honest, without a better idea of your architecture, I can't help much.

Comment: Well basically, I wanted to centralize the management of the coredata functionality. For example - getting a list of items I'd just call [cdManager getItems]; which would just retrieve an NSArray of Items. I did this so that I could have all the data model related code in one place, and that way it wouldn't be repeated. So, for adding it would be [cdManager addItem: item] - this way I can pass an item object, which would 'delay' the creation process until it does it in the addItem method.

Comment: In that case I would just initialize your manager class with a managed object context.

Comment: Yeah, I do already. But my question is with creating an Item before sending it to the addItem method. But from the looks of it, I need the context to actually create the item object properly. The work around I've been using is by passing the values via the addItem method rather than passing the item object and just building the object within the method instead of before. (ie. `[cdManager addItem: itemName withSerial: serial]` - both of those parameters being NSString objects). So I guess that's my only option... hmm

Comment: Reading the comments, seems like this is not the actual answer, could you please update how did you solve your issue? I'm facing the same one here

Comment: The answer here, 3 years later, is to not be an idiot and just fire up a managed object context immediately. I mean, why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

The standard init method for an `NSManagedObject` subclass is `-initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.  If you don't provide a context, call:

```
[myManagedObjectContext insertObject:item];
```

...which is what the init method does internally.  You'll still need to save the managedObjectContext as usual.

Comment: Added a comment in response to both of you on the first answer.