# NSManagedObject setter giving me [ MyObject setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have created an NSManagedObject via xcode Editor menu. My object only has one property "name".  When I try to set the property I get "[MyObject setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
MyObject *thing = [MyObject objectFromJSONDictionary:obj];
thing.name = obj; <-- ERROR HERE
```

I have checked that my property "name" is the same in CD as in my class. Also my interface property is the same. And my dynamic property is the same.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@dynamic name;
```

Any suggestions? And yes I have wiped out the CD object, cleaned my project, and created it in CD again. Same issue?

Comment: remove that `@dynamic name;`

Comment: @MidhunMP: No, **Core Data accessor** methods are dynamically created at runtime, and therefore declared as `@dynamic`.

Comment: What does `objectFromJSONDictionary` do ? The most probably reason is that it does not initialize the Core Data object properly.

Comment: @martinR you are correct.  Not sure why I can't just create [MyObject new] then save it to CD later.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:), `NSManagedObject` *must* be initialized with `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:) Class Reference:

> If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the
>   designated initializer
>   (`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`).

There is also a convenience method

```
+[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]
```

that can be used to create the managed object.

The accessor methods of Core Data objects are created dynamically at runtime,
so one reason for this restriction is that the *entity description* has to be known.

You can create an object with a `nil` context and add it to a managed object context later, see for example: [How can I associate an NSManagedObject to the context after it has been initialised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547053/how-can-i-associate-an-nsmanagedobject-to-the-context-after-it-has-been-initiali)

Comment: Note that if you wish to create an `NSManagedObject` and not insert it into a context immediately, you cannot use the convenience method.