# unrecognized selector sent to instance with Coredata Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, core-data

I keep getting this error whenever I try to update a value of core data model.
Here is my model

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Habit)
class Habit: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var trackingType: NSNumber
}
```

Here is my code tableViewCell

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {
            self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            if self.habit? != nil {
                self.habit?.trackingType = index

            }

        } else {
            self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
        // Configure the view for the selected state

    }
```

I keep getting error **"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Habit setTrackingType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdcbb002c90'"**

at line 
self.habit?.trackingType = index

I am struggling to fix this for last 2 days.

Edit:

The model habit is initialized in below way

```
func getHabits() -> [AnyObject]{
        let entityDescription =
        NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Habit",
            inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entityDescription
//        
//        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(trackingType != -1)")
//        request.predicate = pred

        var error: NSError?

        var objects = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(request,
            error: &error)

        return objects!;
    }
```

The returned list is used everywhere in the app. Basically I fetch and item from the list and update its attributes and then save it again

Comment: Where/how is `self.habit` initialized? Perhaps you did not use the *designated initializer* `init(entity: ,
insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)` ? Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835525/nsmanagedobject-setter-giving-me-myobject-setname-unrecognized-selector-sen.

Comment: I have already gone through all those links but none of them could help. I have edited my question for your comments

Comment: I think this has to do something with the memory but I am not able to figure out in swift

Comment: How is `index` defined?

Comment: Did you auto generate the class?

Comment: No index is defined. Yes I have generated the class using xcode from model

Comment: What the error means is that your Habit class does not *implement* `setTrackingType:`.  You *declared* it, but the implementation was never defined.

Comment: Here is another go answer if using Swift 3, XCode Beta 8 - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50885

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok so the reason you are getting the error is most certainly because the object referenced by `self.habit` is not a `Habit` object. The easiest way to find out what the object really is is to call:

```
print(NSStringFromClass(habit.class))
```

With core data and custom `NSManagedObjects` you need to make sure that the entity: 'Habit' (in your data model) has a class set to Habit. This makes sure that Core Data casts your fetched objects with an entity description of 'Habit' to the Habit class. If you are not doing this then the `getHabits` func will be returning an array of `NSManagedObject`s not an array of `Habit`s.If this is the case then the code: `println(NSStringFromClass(habit.class))` will print "NSManagedObject" to the debugger.

As a side note, you really need to check for errors when you fetch objects from a Core Data database. Add the lines:

```
if objects? == nil {
    print("An error occurred \error.localisedDescription")
}
```

Please forgive my swift if there are any errors, I normally use Objective-C.

EDIT: In order to correct `Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'X'` error. This error is fired when you do not correctly instantiate an `NSManagedObject`. You must not call `[[MyManagedObject alloc] init];` you have to call `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext` instead:

```
MyManagedObject *obj = [[MyManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyManagedObject" inManagedObjectContext:context] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
```

If you do not want the object `obj` to be inserted into a context you can pass through a `nil` context argument. However, if you want undo management and the ability to save the object to the database it needs to be associated with a context.

If you want to have a custom initialisation of an object then you can override the `awakeFromInsert` and `awakeFromFetch` methods/functions.

Comment: I changed the code  as below 'code' if self.habit? != nil {
                NSLog(NSStringFromClass(self.habit?.classForCoder))
                self.habit?.trackingType = index
                
            } 'code' and it is printing the class name correctly as Habit.  CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Habit' 
 Habit
 -[Habit setTrackingType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe452299010
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Habit setTrackingType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Comment: Are you calling `self.habit = [[Habit alloc] init];` (or swift equivalent) anywhere? The error: `Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class` usually means that you are incorrectly initialising the Habit object. Instead of `alloc` `init` you NEED to call: `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. You can pass through `nil` for the `NSManagedObjectContext` if you don't want the `Habit` object to be associated with a context. See my edit for code.