# CoreData error with setter method

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm getting this nasty crash error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Match setParentGameID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7972d710'
```

So I figured either I'm trying to set a value for a key that does't exist, or I'm using an invalid value somewhere. I checked through my file, and the only place where I set parentGameID for a Match object is with this line:

```
Match.createInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!, date: "12/12/12", parentID: g.id)
```

where g.id is a String value. My Match class looks like this:

```
class Match: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var date: String
@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var parentGameID: String

class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, date: String, parentID: String) -> Match {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Match", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Match
        newItem.date = date
        newItem.id = NSUUID().UUIDString
        newItem.parentGameID = parentID

        return newItem
    }

}
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Check this link and see if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514543/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-with-coredata-swift

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had forgotten to change one of my data models to reflect the changes made in the first one. Added the needed attribute, and my code ran well.