# Custom-typed Core Data attributes problem

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want in an entity called `Room`, to have an array of the entity `Person` (basically I want an attribute in Room with a custom type Person), but when doing `room.persons = currentRoomPersons` the application is blocked and a `SIGARBT` error occurs, the current code it's something like this ([Github code](https://github.com/nameszian/testingCoreData)):

Room+CoreDataClass.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Room)
public class Room: NSManagedObject {}
```

Room+CoreDataProperties.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
extension Room {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Room> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Room>(entityName: "Room")
    }

    @NSManaged public var persons: [Person]? // Array of entity "Person" in the room.
}
```

`SIGARBT` this is what it says:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Room setPersons:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001d1eee0'`

The project you can use to run it on your own, or check all the code is uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/nameszian/testingCoreData).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514543/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-with-coredata-swift.

Comment: The reason for the error is that you have not defined any attributes (or relationships) for the Room entity in the data model editor.  But, as @vadian says in his answer, you would do well to use a relationship rather than attribute.

Comment: I do not think it's a duplicate, I think they're different problems, besides it's a post from 2015. Things change.

Answer (score 0):

Entities must be connected to each other with *Relationships* rather than being declared as *Attribute*.

Please read the section [Defining Attributes and Relationships in Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1)

The type of a `To-Many` relationship is `NSSet?` by default. It's highly recommended yo change the type to **non-optional** native `Set<Person>`

Comment: You can declare `To-One` and `To-Many` relationships. It depends on your needs.

Comment: You cannot use an `NSManagedObject` subclass as an **attribute**. The section says that you have to create a subclass if the attribute type is not one of the supported basic types.

Comment: I read your `xcdatamodeld` file. There are no relationships, only entities and attributes. And the type of a `To-Many` relationship is **never** an Array, it's always a Set

Comment: I have changed the custom attributes in a subclass of `NSManagedObject` by relationship To-Many as you said, and now when I do `room.persons = persons` I get this message `Cannot assign value of type '[Person]' to type 'NSSet?'` how I do this?: `It's highly recommended yo change the type to non-optional native Set<Person>` Code updated on Github. (I deleted the previous comments, I did not want to create confusion)

Comment: Set and Array are not related to each other. But you can make a set from the array and assign this. You should create the subclasses *manually* to be able to change the types from Foundation to native Swift types.

Comment: `change the types from Foundation to native Swift types`? What? Some more extensive clue.

Comment: Never mind, you can use `NSSet`, too, but it's less comfortable because you have always to cast the type.

Comment: How would you do it without making casting? Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the data model file you have to set the `Codegen` popup menu of the entities to `Manual/None` and then you have to create the `NSManagedObject` subclasses *manually* from the `Editor` menu. This allows you to change the types of the `NSManaged` properties.

Comment: Ok I Know how to create a subclass of NSManagedObject, That's what I did the first time, but with an attribute not with a relationship. Change from default `@NSManaged public var persons: NSSet?` to `@NSManaged public var persons: [Person]?` ? Because it does not work. Can you tell me exactly how I have to do it? So I can learn, thanks...

Comment: Once again, a `To-Many` relationship **must** be a set (`Set<Person>`). It cannot be an array.

Comment: Initialize Set: `var persons:Set<Person> = Set<Person>()`, Insert Value: `persons.insert(person)` and then `room.persons = persons` works perfectly. Thanks.