# Coredata crash when storing Entity

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data, persistence

I've been trying to use CoreData and I am facing this situation.

After creating my [.xcdatamodeld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O83af.png)

I started to test all entities individually, creating the object, saving then into the Coredata, fetching them back and printing all stored values of that specific Entity. Everything was going pretty well. So I created a point where I would get all the specific ManagedObjects Entities and set them on the `CompletedGameResultManagedObject` that is my central point in this specific model.

This is the CompletedGameResultManagedObject method used to setup the values before saving in CoreData

```
func managedObject(from context: NSManagedObjectContext){

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: String(describing: CompletedGameResultManagedObject.self), in: context)

    let newData = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! CompletedGameResultManagedObject

    //Relationships
    newData.gamePlayedInformation = gamePlayedInformation.managedObject(from: context)
    newData.environmentInformation = environmentInformation.managedObject(from: context)
    newData.gameResultData = result.managedObject(from: context)

    //Entity Properties
    newData.studentIdentifier = studentIdentifier
    newData.tutorIdentifier = tutorIdentifier
}
```

That method, the persistence with CoreData, crashes my app with this [Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIH0c.png)

This is solved, if for some reason I go and comment any `newData` attribution. Transforming whatever one of the lines into a comment, makes my CoreData works. Basically, if I comment

```
    //newData.gamePlayedInformation = gamePlayedInformation.managedObject(from: context)
```

CoreData will be able to save the `CompletedGameResultManagedObject`.

I tried commenting and uncommenting each and every one of the lines to see if the problem was coming out from one of them, and it would work smoothly in all cases that I had at least one line commented.

I've added these Arguments to help debug:

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`

`-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`

`-com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug 1`

I Still could not understand what was going on.

Tried to see if some value were corrupted before calling the CoreData Save Method. But it was not the case, all values were correct and were saved and fetched correctly when I persist the data with one of the properties or relationship attribution line commented.

This makes no sense at all. I am completely lost in understanding why it crashes and why it works if a comment a line.

Comment: Have you checked if each object passed to `newData` is the correct CLass/type? Check this answer if it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514543/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-with-coredata-swift.

Comment: @F.Igor. Yeah! All objects passed to `newData` are correct. I've done a lot of prints checking the values passed to newData and it's working like a charm. Like I said in the question, if, for some reason I comment at least one: `newData = some object`, it saves on CoreData. Doesn't matter which line I choose to comment, as long as I have at least one line commented like in the example, it is capable of storing into CoreData.

Comment: You could probably check your implementation of Managed objects. Try to do a step by step debug, especially stepping into those lines calling .managedObject()