# Trouble mutating NSManagedObject in Swift, Unrecognized Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, mobile

I'm working in a project that is mixed with both swift 3 and objective-c. I have an NSManagedObject called 'TimeSheet' that I have created and added to my DataModel. My call looks like this:

```
let timeSheet = TimeSheet()
timeSheet.clockInTime = clockInDate
```

It creates the TimeSheet object, and when I debug, I can clearly see that it is of the class TimeSheet.

My TimeSheet.h and TimeSheet.m look like this, respectively:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Project, Contact;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TimeSheet : NSManagedObject



@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* clockInTime;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* clockOutTime;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* jobinTime;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* jobOutTime;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* breakStartTime;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSDate* breakOutTime;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) Contact* contact;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) Project* project;

@end

@interface TimeSheet (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addContactObject:(Contact *)value;
- (void)addProjectObject:(Project *)project;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and

```
#import "TimeSheet.h"
#import "Contact.h"
#import "Project.h"

@implementation TimeSheet

@dynamic clockInTime;
@dynamic clockOutTime;
@dynamic jobinTime;
@dynamic jobOutTime;
@dynamic breakStartTime;
@dynamic breakOutTime;
@dynamic contact;
@dynamic project;

@end
```

The Exact Error message that I'm getting looks like this:

```
2016-10-20 14:37:41.357 TimeTracker[16919:31725233] -[TimeSheet setClockInTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000a4d40
2016-10-20 14:37:41.368 TimeTracker[16919:31725233] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-     [TimeSheet setClockInTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000a4d40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c84d34b       __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b53a21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c8bcf34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c7d2c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c7d2798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TimeTracker                         0x0000000107c38927 _TFC19ConstructionUnified25TimeTrackerViewController14clockInPressedfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 695
    6   TimeTracker                         0x0000000107c391d6 _TToFC19ConstructionUnified25TimeTrackerViewController14clockInPressedfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000109ad7b88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000109c5d2b2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000109c5d5cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000109c5c4c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000109b450d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000109b467c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000109af3a33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010a2e5b6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a2de817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c7f2311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c7d759c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c7d6a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c7d6494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110d07a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000109ad5f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  TimeTracker                         0x0000000107b7414f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d90a68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

---

EDIT: Check MartinR's answer in the comments. It solved my problem

---

Comment: `let timeSheet = TimeSheet()` is not a correct way to create a managed object. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject: If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated initializer (init(entity:insertInto:)). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835525/nsmanagedobject-setter-giving-me-myobject-setname-unrecognized-selector-sen.

Comment: I believe you need to insert the model into your ManagedObjectContext

Comment: @MartinR Yep, that was exactly what I needed. I swear, I can be an idiot sometimes haha. Thanks for the help!